# How do I access the raw pdf file via javascript embedded in an object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a page which presents a pdf on the page using an `<embed>` tag. I would like to access the raw file so that the PDF can be automatically sent somewhere via a POST request. I could grab the source of the `<embed>`, do a GET request, and then I would have it. I am trying to find a away to do it without having to make a second request for the same file.

Where is this file temporarily stored once it is fetched?

How can I get the raw data of this file?

```
<embed src="https://www.website.com/mypdf.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
```

Comment: Not sure you can, but if your wanting to send it via a POST request, why not just send the URL, and get the Server end to download it?.

Comment: I don't think its possible either. However, it will likely be cached, which you can verify on the "net" tab of the browser console, so the 2nd request will likely not be an issue